# Javascript TileMap not re-drawing in Gameloop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I set-up a simple canvas tile map with one player object that should move in keydown. So far it is working as I am clearing the canvas in the beginning on every gameLoop, however I noticed that the tile map is drawn only the first time and after the clearRect of the canvas, it just disappears. Can you please help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Tile Map</title>
    <style>
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="400px" width="500px"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var mapArray = [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ];




        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // DRAW PLAYER

        var player = new Object();
        player.y = canvas.height / 2 - 40;
        player.x = canvas.width / 2 - 40;
        player.Width = 80;
        player.Height = 80;
        player_image = new Image();
        player_image.src = 'https://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/horseright1.png';




        function drawPlayer() { // drawing the player
            context.beginPath();
            context.drawImage(player_image, player.x, player.y, player.Width, player.Height);
            context.closePath();
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //SOME VARS


        var updateX = (player.x - 210); // Starting point of canvas X
        var updateY = (player.y - 160); // Starting point of canvas Y
        var posX = updateX;
        var posY = updateY;




        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //DRAW THE MAP     

        function drawMap() {

            var posY = 0;

            var grass = new Image();
            var stone = new Image();

            grass.src = 'https://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/grass.jpeg';
            stone.src = 'https://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/1/images/tile/sand.jpeg';


            grass.onload = function() {
                stone.onload = function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
                            if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
                                context.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, 32, 32);
                            }
                            if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
                                context.drawImage(stone, posX, posY, 32, 32);
                            }
                            posX += 32;
                        }
                        posY += 32;
                        posX = updateX;

                        drawPlayer();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // PLAYER MOVEMENT

        document.onkeydown = function(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            if (keyCode == 39) {
                player.x = player.x + 10; // right is pressed
            }
            if (keyCode == 37) {
                player.x = player.x - 10; // left is pressed
            }
            if (keyCode == 38) {
                player.y = player.y - 10; // up is pressed
            }
            if (keyCode == 40) {
                player.y = player.y + 10; // down is pressed
            }
        }


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // THE GAME LOOP 

        function gameLoop() {


            drawMap();


            setInterval(gameLoop, 100); // 100 milisec to draw next frame
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



        gameLoop(); // start the gameLoop
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The actual drawing just happens in the `onload` handler of the images. The images are loaded just once, so the map is drawn just once.

Comment: That make sense now to me, though do you have any idea on how this can be updated to make it work ? Was giving it a though for awhile now and still can't come up with any solution?  The player is drawn by the context.drawImage , however I somehow doubt that I can do that for the tilemap for loop..

Comment: I think that I came with the solution. I just declared the images and their path inside the drawMap function, so whenever it's called, it is declaring the images again and that makes it work. The only issue I have now as I noticed is that the map keeps redrawing every time beneath itself :D. So in less than a second it goes off the screen, Any ideas on how to fix that one ? Just tried changing the posY+=32; to posY=0; ,but then it draws everything on the same row.

Comment: Re-edited the code in the question to show the solution from earlier.

Comment: Sorry for spamming. Just came to me to declare the posY=0; in the beginning of the drawMap and that fixed it, so it was not updating it's value +32 every time that function is called. Just edited the code from above again - though it does not seems to be the smoothest way to use canvas I think :)

Comment: To sum it up, now everything is working, however is flashing all the time (which I am not sure how to fix). That basically is the last thing left to take care off. Will appreciate any ideas on that. And thanks already for the first suggestion!

Comment: Hope you won't hate me for writing everything that occurs to my mind here. Fixed that one as well. Apperantly I had to add the drawPlayer(); function to the drawMap at the end after it draws all the tiles. That kind of fixed it this time. I guess all my questions have been answered and everything is working now. Updated the questions with the right code and thank you BlackJack for the suggestion! :)